# Grep from txt file (JSON format)

Tags: json, bash, shell, grep

I have a txt in a JSON format:

```
{
  "items": [ {
    "downloadUrl" : "some url",
    "path": "yxxsf",
    "id" : "abc",
    "repository" : "example",
    "format" : "zip",
    "checksum" : {
      "sha1" : "kdhjfksjdfasdfa",
      "md5" : "skjfhkjshdfkjshfkjsdhf"
    }
  }],
  "continuationToken" : null
}
```

I want to extract download url context (in this example i want "some url") using grep and store it in another txt file. TBH i have never used grep

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual file contents into your question instead of posting a picture of them. Then, grep is the wrong tool for JSON parsing; you should use something like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this. And finally, if you have never used grep, it feels like you're expecting somebody else to do your work; you have to make an effort yourself first.

Comment: I was expecting a syntax of grep that can find that particular url.
Thank you for your time. I researched about it and found the solution using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although json `string` may contain double-quote character escaped by
a backslash, both a double quote and a backslash in URLs should be
percent-encoded according to RFC 3986. Then you can extract the URL with:

```
tr "[:space:]" " " < file.json | grep -Po '"downloadUrl"\s*:\s*\K"[^"]+"'
```

- Let me use `tr` to pre-process the json file to convert all `blank`
  characters to whitespaces. Then the following `grep` will work
  if the name and the value pair are in the separate (but consecutive) lines.
- The `\K` operator in the regex is a variable-length look-behind without
  including the preceding pattern in the matched result.

Note that the command above works with the provided example but may not
be robust enough for arbitrary inputs. I'd still recommend to use `jq`
for the strict purpose.

Comment: grep -oP 'some..([^"]+)*' worked perfect for me. Thanks for the answer tho. Really appreciate that

Comment: @Peace9795 thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. If you consider your problem is well solved with my answer, I'd appreciate if you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `grep`**

```
grep -oP 'downloadUrl"\s:\s"(.*)",' myfile > urlFile.txt
```

See this Regex in action: https://regex101.com/r/DvnXCO/1

**A better way to do this is to use `jq`**

Download `jq` for Windows: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

```
jq ".items[0].downloadUrl" myfile > urlFile.txt
```

Comment: I would like to it with grep only 
That command also copied downloadUrl" : "some url",
I just want some url no commas no colons

Comment: @Peace9795, be mindful that grep solution is prone to failures. E.g.: `"downloadUrl":` label and `"some url"` could reside on different lines, which is still a valid JSON, but will break grep based solutions

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use only grep:

```
grep downloadURL myfile > new_file.txt
```

If you prefer a cleaner option, adding `cut` command:

```
grep downloadURL myfile | cut -d\" -f4 > new_file.txt
```

BTW the image of the json file shows that you are using notepad (windows?)

Comment: Yes,I'm on windows running a bash script to get the url. 
I have used curl to get that information and put it in a txt file

Comment: It didn't work. The new file is empty
FYI: I want to extract only "some url" (if you see the text file)